# nodejs isn't getting default cookie that django sets for users

Tags: django, node.js, cookies, header, production-environment

I have just pushed a web app into production and requests to my nodejs no longer contain the user cookie that Django has been setting by default on my localhost (where it was working).

my nodejs looks for the cookie like this

```
io.configure(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if (data.headers.cookie) {
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error',false);
    });
    io.set('log level',1);
});
```

and on localhost has been getting this

```
cookie: 'username="name:1V7yRg:n_Blpzr2HtxmlBOzCipxX9ZlJ9U"; password="root:1V7yRg:Dos81LjpauTABHrN01L1aim-EGA"; csrftoken=UwYBgHUWFIEEKleM8et1GS9FuUPEmgKF; sessionid=6qmyso9qkbxet4isdb6gg9nxmcnw4rp3' },
```

in the request header.

But in production, the header is the same but except no more cookie.  Does Django only set this on localhost?  How can I get it working in production?

I've tried setting these in my settings.py

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

But so far no good.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: Did you also set the template tag `csrf_token` in the template?

Comment: Yes.  Both development and production use the same templates

Comment: That wasn't what I asked.

Comment: Sorry I meant yes the template tag is in the template.  It's working for localhost and not production yet they're using the same template

Comment: Can you see the cookie with firebug or similar?

Comment: And the token is rendered correctly on production as well? Compare the html output of the two templates.

Comment: The token has rendered correctly.  And I checked my browser and the cookies are being set.  It's just they aren't in the request to nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.  I was making a request to nodejs on the client like this

```
Message.socket = io.connect('http://123.456.789.10:5000');
```

Where I used my respective IP address and port that my nodejs was listening on.  This is considered cross domain so browsers won't include cookies in the request.  Easy fix by changing it to

```
Message.socket = io.connect('http://www.mydomain.com:5000');
```